# how to get the selected value field of listbox vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox, selectedvalue, selectedindexchanged

Hope u r doing well.

I have Listbox, that I want to assign primary key, and a text (eg. students table). So i wrote this code.

```
    mySQLCmd.CommandText = "SELECT studentname, studentid FROM studentstable WHERE Year(DOB) = " + selectedYear
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()
    dt.Load(myReader)
    Listbox1.datavaluefield = "studentid"
    Listbox1.datatextfield = "studentname"
    ListBox1.DataSource = dt
    ListBox1.DataBind()
```

The listbox works fine. SQL statement works fine. And I want to catch selectedvalue and selecteditem properties on  ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged

```
    1. Dim selectedPupil As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
    2. Dim selectedPupilID As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedValue
```

When I select something on the listbox, both of selecteditem and selectedvalue properties just return the student name, not the student id. So I get this error.

```
    Error on Line2. Conversion from string "RichardCole" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

I don't know why? So i do i get the studentid value back ? I need to know the ID coz name can't use as PK so.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  mySQLCmd.CommandText = "SELECT studentname, studentid FROM studentstable WHERE Year(DOB) = " + selectedYear
Dim dt As New DataTable
myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()
dt.Load(myReader)
Listbox2.DataValueField = "studentid"    'it was ListBox1 now ListBox2
Listbox2.DataTextField = "studentname"   'it was ListBox1 now ListBox2
ListBox2.DataSource = dt
ListBox2.DataBind()
```

The other thing is use ListBox2 not one
**Updated**:

```
  Dim selectedPupil As String = ListBox2.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()
Dim selectedPupilID As Integer = Ctype(ListBox2.SelectedValue, Integer) 'convert the value to integer
```

or make the variable a string

```
  Dim selectedPupilID As String = ListBox2.SelectedValue
```

Or change all the above ListBoxes to `ListBox1`, but don't mix them this way

Comment: Listbox1 and 2 is just typing error, you seem to put Text.ToString() as well ? would that make a difference coz the problem is the ID not the studentname.

Comment: Of course selectedItem.Text makes difference because this one is string while selectedItem is an object which may throw an error when the compiler tries to parse

Comment: it doesn't make a difference. I updated the error I got. would u still like to help?

Comment: I got it fixed, I am not sure how I fixed it though. I just made a new project and redo everything as the same way I did but it fixed. Thanks.

Comment: The problem says you're assigning the ListBox1.SelectedValue (which is of type string) to a variable which is integer. So you could have parsed it to integer, See the update of my answer. Now infact, you solved it, but for information purpose I'm trying to explain. See the update of my answer above

Comment: thanks and yes, that was indeed the problem .. i fixed it by changing string to both variables which i shouldn't really do. Your updated answer is really useful.

Answer (score 3):

You set the value and text fields on listbox1 but you are binding the data to listbox2.  So, unless I am missing something else, that seems like it could be the problem.

Where is listbox1 filled/bound?

Comment: ohh .. sorry that's just the copy of paste error when i am making this post.

Comment: I don't see any problems with what you show here directly.  Look for other references to listbox1 and make sure that nothing else is altering the databinding, also you can get rid of the .toString on the text property of the selectedItem since its already a string.

Comment: Oh, and be sure that the code that loads the listbox isn't happening each postback.  I can't see how that would get you the name instead of an empty string, but best to be sure

Comment: I got it fixed, I am not sure how I fixed it though. I just made a new project and redo everything as the same way I did but it fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.  yay for mysteries.